# Is it possible to hook into the Changes Tab to save CSS and JS changes made in DevTools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am creating an extension to track changes that have been made to any JS or CSS file of a page via DevTools. At will, I want to then push those changes - as a whole file if necessary, but changed-elements only would be nice - for the purpose of sending directly to my server to be handled.

My question pertains specifically to this:

[Image of DevTools Changed Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLD0a.jpg)

**Can I, via an extension, hook into the Changes tab in order to take those changes and process them?** (Or is there a similar process that can handle this manually?)

This ideal output I'm hoping to find or be able to get to would be something like this:

```
{
    fileName: nameofeditedfile.css,
    change: [SomeComplexObjectWithTheSpecificChanges]
}
```

I'm aware that I can save these files locally and then do as I please with them, but for multiple reasons that's definitely NOT the route I want to go.

Let me know if I need to include a more specific example or other details!

Comment: See [devtools protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) for available commands. The only related event I see is [CSS.styleSheetChanged](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/CSS#event-styleSheetChanged).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, I explored something similar as an option but it doesn't go quite as far as what I was hoping for. For posterity: since the CSS domain is experimental, I didn't want to have any dependency on it so I accomplished a similar result with [onResourceContentCommitted](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow#event-onResourceContentCommitted). Resulted in references to the file and the full file contents of the stylesheet that was changed, but obviously not an ideal solution for what I'm asking.